# Delete rsvp option of suggesting new meeting time from created ics file

Tags: outlook, icalendar

How do I delete the rsvp option of suggesting a new meeting time as you can see in the screenshot?

Deleting the `;mailto:user1@example.com` part does exactly that, so that only the three usual rsvp buttons are left, but I also don't receive any rsvp mails any more.

[image: option to suggest new time]

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//xy.com//Appointment v1.0//DE
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20240311T080000Z@xy.com
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20240311T080000
DTSTART:20240311T140000Z
DTEND:20240311T143000Z
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEED-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;mailto:user1@example.com
ORGANIZER;CN="userxy":MAILTO:x.y@outlook.de
LOCATION:earth
DESCRIPTION:Hello,\n\nGreetings.
SUMMARY:Meeting on earth
CLASS:PRIVATE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I am thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER` ICS header to `TRUE`:

```
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-REQUESTEDATTENDANCEMODE:DEFAULT
X-MICROSOFT-ISRESPONSEREQUESTED:TRUE
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works! The problem I have now is that when I attach the file I created to an email, forward it to myself (email from nuun@example.com to nuun@example.com) and accept it, I receive a confirmation on my organizer email account, x.y@outlook.de. When I forward it to a colleague, I don't get a confirmation of his acceptance. How can I change that? (The mailto:user1@example.com is contrary to the others literally the one in my txt file, I am not using an existing attendee email address)

Comment: Hard to say without actually seeing the ICS file, but the general rule of thumb in case your code behaves differently from what Outlook does, send an appointment from Outlook to a Gmail mailbox and then look at the invitation source in the Gmail mailbox - it lets you look at the raw MIME source of the invitation.